# python - get cookie expiry time using the requests library

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to get the expiry time of a specific cookie that I retrieve from the server as:

```
s = requests.session()
r = s.get("http://localhost/test")
r.cookies
```

This will list all cookies sent by the server (I get 2 cookies) as:

```
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie PHPSESSID=cusa6hbtb85li8po
argcgev221 for localhost.local/>, <Cookie WebSecu=f for localhost.local/test>]>
```

When I do:

```
r.cookies.keys
```

I get:

```
<bound method RequestsCookieJar.items of <<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCooki
eJar'>[Cookie(version=0, name='PHPSESSID', value='30tg9vn9376kmh60ana2essfi3', p
ort=None, port_specified=False, domain='localhost.local', domain_specified=False
, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires
=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False), Co
okie(version=0, name='WebSecu', value='f', port=None, port_specified=False, doma
in='localhost.local', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/test', path_specified=False, secure=False, expires=1395491371, discard=Fals
e, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>>
```

As you can see, we have two cookies. I would like to get the expiry time of the cookie named "WebSecu"

Thank you

Answer (score 13):

In `requests`, the cookie jar is a very special object. You might notice that if you do:

```
r.cookies['WebSecu']
```

You'll receive the value of that cookie as a string (in your example `f`). To get the actual cookie object that holds that information, you will have to iterate over the cookie jar like so:

```
expires = None
for cookie in r.cookies:
    if cookie.name == 'WebSecu':
        expires = cookie.expires
```

Comment: A more 'Pythonic' way: `expires = next(x for x in r.cookies if x.name == 'WebSecu').expires`

Comment: 'Pythonic' is a word bandied about by people trying to sound superior. If 'Pythonic' were to mean anything of value, it would mean "Easy to understand". If you were to give someone your one-liner and the for-loop above, most would have to take extra time to understand the one-liner. (Especially most of the people trying to learn from this site.)

Comment: I've followrd this method and although my SESSION_COOKIE_AGE is 3600 I get 1510315939, this is not milliseconds, what is this? It seems it has nothing to do with my  SESSION_COOKIE_AGE.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 agreed.  I don't see what's great about the one-liner either.  It works the same but seems obscure and superficial.

Comment: Old stuff but wanted to point out that there is big difference between the solution in the answer and the above 'pythonic' way. Imagine multiple cookies with same name, answer's solution will pick the last cookie, while the onliner will pick the first one in the iteration. They are not same.

Comment: @DidinaDeen That's the expiry date as a timestamp. do `from datetime import datetime; print(datetime.fromtimestamp(expires))` to see it as a human-readable date and time.

Comment: @ocket8888's precision should be added to the answer to make it clearer. At least mention ```expires``` is a timestamp, which at first sight I thought was a boolean.