# cookies as a global variable

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I have a program which dowloads images from some site (using python 3.4). The downloading is performed from several functions in the program. And every time in every function I get cookies from the site. Is it possible to make global variable "pk", get cookies 1 time and assign them to that variable "pk"? And then in every function just to check if cookies are still valid. If valid - use them, if not - get new ones.

I made global variable:

```
pk=requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
```

I get cookies from the site and assign them to variable:

```
with requests.Session() as v:
    try:
        p = v.post('http:...index.php', data=payload)
    except:
        time.sleep(5)
    pk=v.cookies
```

But I can't find a way to check if cookies are still valid, or even to check if they are there. this way doesn't work:

```
if pk=={}:
    print ("getting new cookies")
else:
    print ("using old cookies")
```

"pk" has cookies inside, I can print them out, but case "else" never happens to work.

Please help to write working if...else instruction.

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly. I would say that saving a session variable as global variable should work better. But you should always try to make a complete and minimal example. Almost always, you should have only one chunk of code. And ban "doesn't work". If you get an error, copy the entire error message. If it runs, but you want an other output, say "Program output this, but I want that"

Comment: Also, if you want more answers, try add python tag.

Comment: Thanks, 1) python tag - I have python3-x tag. Isn't it enough? If no, I'll add python tag. 2) what I want - (I already have global variable with cookies inside) now I want a way to check if cookies inside that variable  are still valid or should I get new ones.

Comment: cookies are not eternal, right? they can be used for some time and then I have to get new ones, right? and I do not know the way how to check if my cookies are still usable or should I get new ones, because my old ones expired.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577182/python-get-cookie-expiry-time-using-the-requests-library ?

Comment: Python has 54k followers and python-3.x has  3k. If you want 18x more readers...