# python 3 requests try-except failure

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, try-except

I have a program which downloads pages from a site, finds links for pictures in them and downloads those pictures. If I try to run this program on a computer with fast and stable Internet connection - everything works perfectly for days and weeks. But if I try this program on a computer with slow or not stable Internet connection - I have one problem - the "try-except" module doesn't seem to work correctly.

--- this function downloads content - any content (page or picture)

```
def downl(self,addr,cook,head2,errmess):
    global result
    try:
        result=requests.get(addr, cookies=cook, headers=head2)
    except:
        print(errmess) # error message
        time.sleep(5)
    return result
```

I sent to this function link to the page, then other function looks for picture_link in that page, and then I send to the same function (downl) picture_link. After this I save result of function (downl) as a .jpg file. As I told - on a computer with normal internet connection everything works fine. As a result I have 5, 10 or 5000 pictures on my HDD.

But let me show little example of what happens with bad internet connection. Suppose we have 2 pages and 1 picture in every page.

```
step 1) downloading 1st page (def downl)
step 2) taking picture_link from it
step 3) downloading picture (def downl)
step 4) saving 1st picture to hdd 1.jpg
step 5) downloading 2nd page (def downl)
step 6) taking picture_link from it
step 7) downloading picture (def downl) and receivind error message (errmess)
step 8) saving 2nd picture to hdd 2.jpg
```

just for example: 1st picture may be normal jpg with proper content. The second picture will be file with jpg extension but will have 2nd page as it's content (it will be usual html file, saved with wrong extension "jpg")

another words: there was problem with internet during downloadind of the second picture, the program printed an error about it (errmess), but INSTEAD of COUNTLESS retrying (as supposed in my function) it somehow PASSED through the try-except block and returned previous result (2nd page), which was saved as 2nd picture.

Please help! How to make this try-except (or requests) work FOREVER, UNTILL it downloads what it is supposed to download (no matter what mistakes happen with internet connection), and not pass through with previous result.

Thanks very much for youк time and attention.

Comment: `global result` is causing the 'failed' result to return the last successful result. `result` is not redefined, and still `return`-ed. What is the exact error being thrown? `ConnectionError`?

Comment: yes. I understand that I get previous result because of the global "result". But question is about other thing - why the program passes through try-except, when it should circle in it forever untill it downloads the picture. about exact error - I'll be at the computer with bad internet tonight and look the exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need a while True loop like this:

```
def downl(self,addr,cook,head2,errmess):
    global result
    while(True):
        try:
            result=requests.get(addr, cookies=cook, headers=head2)
            return result
        except:
            print(errmess) # error message
            time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! with your help it works as it's supposed to. ))) We put it in eternal cycle and let it out only after positive result. May I ask for an explanation? Why it doesn't work without while True cycle? isn't try-except supposed to work the same way? Or it is designed to do only one iteration? Does it mean that try-except is not a cycle, that it is just a way not to get program stopped when having a known mistake?

Comment: Your last hypothesis is correct, try -except is just a way to catch exceptions (errors).  If you want a cycle, you have to use a loop (while or for) or a recursive function.

Comment: Eric, thank you very much for you answer. As far as I can judge - you are profi in python. May be you could help me with other question, which nobody even tries to answer fo several weeks? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079454/cookies-as-a-global-variable

Comment: @UserNew: flattery will get you nowhere but don't stop trying ;-) I will have a look.

Comment: ))) All women are exposed to flattery, and they are more than 50% of humanity. The only creatures who are exposed to flattery more than women - are men. ;)